# Calling a selector with unknown number of arguments using reflection / introspection

Tags: objective-c, ios, reflection, introspection

Lately I wrote an application in java (for android) which used reflection to invoke methods of some objects. The argument number and type was unknown, meaning, I had a unified mechanism that received an object name, method name and array of parameters (using JSON) and invoked the specified method on the specified object with an array of the arguments (Object[] filled with arguments of the required types).

Now I need to implement the same for iOS, I was able to invoke a selector when I knew the number of parameters the selector expected for like this:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"FooWithOneArg");
[view performSelectorInBackground:selector withObject:someArg];
```

I know I can get the number of arguments the selector receives by using

```
int numberOfArguments = method_getNumberOfArguments(selector);
```

But is there a way to make a generic call like this:

```
[someObject performSelector:selector withObject:arrayOfObjects]
```

which is pretty much equivalent to Java's

```
someMethod.invoke(someObject, argumentsArray[]);
```

?

I want to avoid a switch case according to the amount of arguments the selector gets.

Sorry for the long dig, I just want to make my question as clear as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This small function should do the trick, its not perfect, but it gives you a starting point:

```
void invokeSelector(id object, SEL selector, NSArray *arguments)
{
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([object class], selector);
    int argumentCount = method_getNumberOfArguments(method);

    if(argumentCount > [arguments count])
        return; // Not enough arguments in the array

    NSMethodSignature *signature = [object methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    [invocation setTarget:object];
    [invocation setSelector:selector];

    for(int i=0; i<[arguments count]; i++)
    {
        id arg = [arguments objectAtIndex:i];
        [invocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:i+2]; // The first two arguments are the hidden arguments self and _cmd
    }

    [invocation invoke]; // Invoke the selector
}
```

Comment: `class_getClassMethod([object class], selector);` I think is wrong.  You should be calling `class_getInstanceMethod();`

Comment: Thanks for giving me this help. I have found a few more issues, and if you don't mind, I'll fix them later (or tell you what they are) for future reference. Thanks again!

Comment: It won't work when used on a class object, because calling `class` on a class object calls `+class`, which just returns the class object itself, not its class. And anyway the first two lines is unnecessary, because you can just get the `argumentCount` from `[signature numberOfArguments]`

Answer (score 3):

With the awesome help here including the simple but perfect answer from user102008 I pulled together the following example. Note what I was really trying to do was allow someone to send me a target selector that either did or did not take an argument. If it takes an argument I assume they want the calling object's "self" returned as a reference:

```
    NSMethodSignature * sig = [target methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if ([sig numberOfArguments] > 0) {
        [target performSelector:selector withObject:self];
    }

    else {
        [target performSelector:selector];
    }
```

Hope this helps someone digging around.

Comment: Just to clarify this, numberOfArguments always returns at least 2 (self, _cmd) so above should read [sig numberOfArguments] > 2 - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmethodsignature_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

I modified @JustSid answer and added more validation, nil argument support, changed it to an Obj-C NSObject category method, and add `-performSelectorIfAvailable:` helper methods for easier use. Please enjoy! :)

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (performSelectorIfAvailable)

// Invokes a selector with an arbitrary number of arguments.
// Non responding selector or too few arguments will make this method do nothing.
// You can pass [NSNull null] objects for nil arguments.
- (void)invokeSelector:(SEL)selector arguments:(NSArray*)arguments {
    if (![self respondsToSelector:selector]) return; // selector not found

    // From -numberOfArguments doc,
    // "There are always at least 2 arguments, because an NSMethodSignature object includes the hidden arguments self and _cmd, which are the first two arguments passed to every method implementation."
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    int numSelArgs = [signature numberOfArguments] - 2;
    if (numSelArgs > [arguments count]) return; // not enough arguments in the array

    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    [invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setSelector:selector];

    for(int i=0; i < numSelArgs; i++) {
        id arg = [arguments objectAtIndex:i];
        if (![arg isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            [invocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:i + 2];
        }
    }
    [invocation invoke]; // Invoke the selector
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not define each of your methods to take one argument: the array of objects?  Presumably what you want is, with with the method

```
-(void) doSomethingWithFoo:(id) foo andBar: (id) bar;
```

to invoke it with the parameters set from the array.  Well, instead have:

```
-(void) doSomethingWithArrayOfFooAndBar: (NSArray*) fooAndBar;
```

then your whole dispatch mechanism just becomes:

```
[someObject performSelector:selector withObject:arrayOfObjects];
```

Comment: Hi JeremyP, I thought about it, but the other methods are not mine, they are methods of code I'm testing. My application is kind of RPC that should invoke method on some object (controlled from a remote PC) I want to avoid wrapping as much as possible to make it easier to adapt new API or API changes.

Comment: @MByD: In that case, I think you are stuck with JustSid's method.  It should work OK.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "stuck", it's pretty much what I was looking for. But I want to see if it works before accepting an answer :)

Comment: @MByD: I only said "stuck" because the necessity to call into the Objective-C runtime directly is often an indication that there is something wrong with the design. I always feel there ought to be an Objective-C way of doing it.  However, in this case, there isn't.  BTW there is a bug in the solution.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Objective-C is a new world for me, and I know I miss many things, unfortunately, I have a close dead line, so first I have to make things work.

Comment: One reason is you can't add `nil` into `NSArray`.